# Authentication using Spring with Heroku

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, heroku

I have an application deployed to Heroku that uses Spring Security, and, by extension, `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository`. Realizing that `HttpSession` will cause problems when scaling up to multiple dynos, I am trying to configure webapp-runner  (https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner) with the `--session_manager memcache` flag (with the Heroku memcache addon).

A local configuration using Apache and `mod_proxy`, two Tomcat instances, and memcached 1.4.13 works fine. When deployed to Heroku, however, it fails, even with a single dyno - randomly redirecting to the login page as if unauthenticated, indicating that the session store is not working. Same Procfile, verified the `MEMCACHE_*` variables via `heroku config`, etc.

Does anyone have experience with a similar configuration?

Comment: Seems like that should work.  Can you use `heroku logs` to verify that the webapp-runner Memcache session management was setup correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: the configuration works as designed.

The issue was caused by a Spring Security mis-configuration. A bad image URL buried in the app triggered the redirect. While this should have simply been a 404, there was also a catch-all `intercept-url` pattern in context-security.xml with access set to `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`. The result was that any page with the bad URL redirected to the login page. Correcting those URLs addressed the problem when deployed to Heroku, though I can't explain why it did not manifest on a local system.